# Finding the z value in finance question

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, finance, moment-generating-functions

For time $t > 0$, let $X_t$ be a random variable **normally** distributed with

$$\mu = 0.08t$$

$$\sigma = 0.02\sqrt{t}$$

Let $S_0$ denote the known
spot price of an asset today and let the random variable $S_t$ denote the
unknown price of the asset in time $t$ years.

Assume
$$St = S_0e^{Xt}$$

(a) If you invest all your personal money today in the asset, by when
do you expect your personal worth to triple?

(b) What is the probability that your worth at least triples after two
year?

For $a$ I set it up so $$E(S_0e^{\mu t +0.02\sqrt{t} Z})$$

Then I used MGF and solved for t.

Part $b$ is where I am stuck. I have it set up so $$P(S_0e^{\mu t +0.02\sqrt{t} Z}> 3S_0)$$
where t=2

From here I solve for Z but the Z value I get is really high. 
So I assume I made a mistake somewhere, or I have the whole thing set up wrong. 
Where would is this mistake?

Comment: So $0.2$ or $0.02$?

Comment: 0.02. thank you for catching that

Comment: Is your z value about $33.185$ ?

Comment: yes, it is around that.

Comment: Is that possible?